# How can i move a text down a line? Enter isn´t working

Tags: dart, visual-studio-code

I want to move the text down a line in dart. Normally i just use "enter" but this doesn´t work here.
If i use "enter" it brings me in the next line, but it doesn´t move down the rest of the text.
[image]

[image]

i tried "ctrl enter" or "alt enter". both are not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have your overtype mode turned on. You can hit the insert key to toggle back.

You can have a look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insert_key) for more information.

Comment: Nice thats the solution ! Thank you Henry Twist, you helped me a lot